# How to create a shared folder on Win7 EC2 and access it from my desktop

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I create a shared folder on Win7 EC2 and access it from my desktop.

My main goal is to copy files, I am able to RDP and copy via Shared Drives however I want to create a shared folder in my EC2 so can automate the deployment process.

I want to access it from my Jenkins straight to \\X.X.X.X\SharedFolder

At the moment I even not being able to ping it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to edit your **Security Group** to allow inbound traffic.

- TCP/IP SMB (used for sharing files) runs on **Port 445**

Please ensure you have sufficient security settings on your Amazon EC2 instance, since opening this port could lead to attempts to access your system.

To enable **Ping** for your Amazon EC2 instance, also permit **ICMP** protocol in the security group.